# replace with regexp is not working (replacing) in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm a newbie with `Ansible` and I'm trying to write a playbook that will check a line and if it is not commented it out, to do it. This is the line I want to comment out with `//`:
`$data['refresh_timeout'] = $data['Timeout'];`

I have checked the syntax of the search in regex101.com and `regexp` seems to work fine. It looks that my problem is with `replace`.
This is my code:

```
replace:
  path: /var/www/html/application/controllers/welcome.php
  regexp: r'^\s+(\$data\[\'refresh_timeout\'\].*)$'
  replace: r'^\s+// (\$data\[\'refresh_timeout\'\]\1'
```

I have been testing in 2 servers, in `mytest-server2` the line is already commented out, but `ansible` does not modify the file in `mytest-server1` (line without comments) when executed. This is what I've got:

```
`TASK [Gathering Facts]************************************************ 
task path: /home/myself/ansible/wui_refresh.yml:5
ok: [mytest-server2] 
ok: [mytest-server1]
META: ran handlers`

`TASK [Check whether /welcome.php contains "// $data['refresh_timeout']"] *****
task path: /home/myself/ansible/wui_refresh.yml:23
ok: [mytest-server1] => {"changed": false, "msg": ""}
ok: [mytest-server2] => {"changed": false, "msg": ""}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers`

`PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************
mytest-server2 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
mytest-server1 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0`
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

The task below does the job

```
- replace:
    path: /var/www/html/application/controllers/welcome.php
    regexp: '^\$data\[''refresh_timeout''\] = \$data\[''Timeout''\];'
    replace: '//$data[''refresh_timeout''] = $data[''Timeout''];'
```

Before

```
$ cat welcome.php
$data['refresh_timeout'] = $data['Timeout'];
```

After

```
$ cat welcome.php
//$data['refresh_timeout'] = $data['Timeout'];
```

Notes

- [Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097) is used for *regexp* and *replace*. Single quotes must be escaped ('').
- *regexp* uses Python regular expressions. Special characters must be escaped (\$ ...)
- If there is one or more white space at the beginning of the line *regexp* must start with '^\s+

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic! It worked, I had to add \s+ in the regexp.
Thank you very much Vladimir!
I voted you up but I only have 5 points :( so it doesn't show...